# MS Office Addin Disappears after closing the office application

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

One of my customers have reported that after installing my addin from the Office Add-ins Store, the addin is automatically removed from office application(Word, Excel) after they close it or if they open back the application after a few days and hence they have to keep installing it from the office add-ins store each time if they want to use it. How can i resolve this issue? Since the issue is happening very randomly, I'm unable to get the appropriate data to resolve it. So far, I've asked them to install the latest version of office, but even that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: This is a bug that should be reported on the Office.js [repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose).